# How to use p5js with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, p5.js

I want to write a library based on [p5js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js), so in my Javascript project I have *Webpack* installed as dev-dependency and I write this in `start.js`:

```
import p5 from "p5";

p5.ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100); // Function not found :(
```

However, no references are found in `p5`. I was expecting to find references to p5's functions like `rect` or `ellipse` or `setup`, but nothing.

#### More info

My Webpack config file is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './start.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'start.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            /* In order to transpile ES6 */
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ],  
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use p5.js in typeScript and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540308/cannot-use-p5-js-in-typescript-and-webpack)

Comment: My solution is to use [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html). All of those objects are only accessible from the argument for the function u give p5.

Answer (score 5):

Like iluvAS said, you need to use instance mode.

```js
// use this import in your webpack. Commented out because the CDN script exposes p5 as global
// import p5 from 'p5'; 

const containerElement = document.getElementById('p5-container');

const sketch = (p) => {
  let x = 100;
  let y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(800, 400);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  };
};

new p5(sketch, containerElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<div id="p5-container"></div>
```

Here is another working example with webpack and es6 module imports hosted on stackblitz (which uses webpack under the hood): https://stackblitz.com/edit/p5-in-webpack

Comment: The poster obviously wants to write the code in non-instance mode, so "use instance mode" is not a great answer which can be interpreted as borderline sarcastic.