# Cannot use p5.js in typeScript and Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, p5.js

I have a project for a library using [p5.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js).

#### Details

My Webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './start.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'start.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: "at",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.8.3",
    "webpack": "4.9.1",
    "webpack-cli": "2.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "p5": "0.6.1"
  }
}
```

I want to use typescript, so `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es5" ],
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": [
    "start.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "out"
  ]
}
```

And entry point `start.ts` is:

```
import * as p5 from "p5";

class entry {
    // Some
}
```

#### Problem

Get this also in intellisense in VSCode, but basically the problem is that `p5` cannot be found. When I run `npm run build` I get:

```
> webpack --config webpack.config.js

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.8.3 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\myproj/tsconfig.json.


[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
Hash: 1ef5f8c2b136b8718342
Version: webpack 4.9.1
Time: 1214ms
Built at: 05/26/2018 8:23:35 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = start.js
[0] ./start.ts 93 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in [at-loader] ./start.ts:1:21
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'p5'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! andry-tino@0.1.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the me@0.1.0 build script 'webpack --config webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myproj package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --config webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myproj
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls andry-tino
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\antino\Documents\GitHub\myproj\npm-debug.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, try to build with `tsc` directly. I think your tsconfig is not right.
Try removing `allowJs', `typeRoots`, `baseUrl`, and `include` in your tsconfig also. Your setting seems strange and not needed.

Comment: Fixed the `tsconfig` and the error from `tsc` is: `start.ts(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'p5'.` But isn't that the point of using webpack : not just bundlingbut also handling imports from all kinds of stuff?

Comment: If you can't transpile with `tsc`, webpack won't do any better.
Remove your `typeRoots`. It's not how it is used. Any 99% of the time you don't need to set it.

Comment: `typeRoots` is used to set the root to lookup types, by default it is `node_modules` which is how `tsc` search for modules.

Comment: Did it, same result :(

Comment: But the point is that TS should not transpile `p5`, it just needs to definitions to compile whatever code I have. The reason for using webpack would be to bundle `p5`...

Comment: But I get maybe you mean: "one problem at a time". So let's focus on why TS won't find the types in `p5` which is strange. The types are in the `p5` folder: `p5.d.ts`, which is also the reason why I had the `typeRoots`

Comment: It will not transpire p5. It is strange that you get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a look at it and it turns out 'p5' typings is not correct. So you can't use it.
Check out some of its issues here: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+typescript

And for you, your config is messing you up in some way.
You can easily see the actual error by creating an `index.ts`:

```
import 'p5'
console.log(p5)
```

and tries to transpile it with `tsc`:

```
node_modules/p5/lib/p5.d.ts(555,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'COLOR_MODE'.
node_modules/p5/lib/p5.d.ts(871,87): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ARC_MODE'.

... removing some errors for brevity

node_modules/p5/lib/p5.d.ts(10312,5): error TS2416: Property 'amp' in type 'Noise' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Oscillator'.
  Type '(volume: number | object, rampTime?: number, timeFromNow?: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(vol: number | object, rampTime?: number, timeFromNow?: number) => AudioParam'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AudioParam'.
```

Since `p5` is used globally and I can't find an example to use is as a module, the following will work fine:

```
// index.ts
declare const p5: any
// code away
```

Answer (score 2):

p5.js has an official typings package. Install it with `npm i @types/p5 --save-dev` will give you real typing instead of the `any` type in the work around posted by unional.

Here is the typings package on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/p5